# Insert content in Jquery isotope

Tags: jquery

I have one div with isotope and I'm trying to insert content in it from another div. But im stuck.

So i tried to get the content from div2 with .html() and insert it into isotope with isotope('insert', div2.html()) and it doesn't work

```
<div id="content1" >
   <div  class="large item"> <img src="images/5.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="small item"> <img src="images/7.jpg" /> </div>
   <div  class="medium item"> <img src="images/6.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="medium item"> <img src="images/13.jpg" /> </div>
  <div class="small item"> <img src="images/7.jpg" /> </div>
</div>
 <div  id="content2" >
  <div class="box item">
  <p>blabla</p>
     <ul>
      <li>
        aaaa
       </li>
  </ul>
   </div>
 </div>

var $container = $('#content1'); 
    $container.isotope({
          // options 
        itemSelector : ".item",
        masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() * 0.125},
        resizable: false,
        animationEngine : 'jquery'

    });

   var $newItems = '';
   $container.isotope( 'insert', $newItems);
```

Now my problem is when i do this

```
var $newItems = $('#content2').html();
```

Nothing happens,  but when i do this

```
var $newItems = $('<div class="box item"><h1> Lorem ipsulm </h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div>');
```

it inserts it with no problem.

EDIT: it has to insert it when i click a button

Comment: why did you add same question twice:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232702/jquery-isotope-inserting-content

Comment: by the way. use firebug or chrome's "inspect element" next time to see the error. I've never worked with isotope, but the error message from the console led me to the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

isotope is expecting a DOM element, not a string.
This worked for me:

```
var node = $('<div/>', {
     html: $('#content2').html()
});
$container.isotope( 'insert', node);
```

Comment: I lost a few hours of my life over this :)